# Uncaught TypeError: can't define property "x": Object is not extensible

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to restore a old project written on `ReactJS 16.4` and packed with `webpack 3`.
As for now I've upgraded all libraries, `ReactJS` to `v17` and `webpack` to `v5`.

So, I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: can't define property "lang": Object is not extensible
```

And the code is:

```
class LandingPage extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const { i18n } = this.props;

    if ((typeof this.props.match.params.lng !== 'undefined') && ((this.props.match.params.lng == 'en') || (this.props.match.params.lng == 'lt'))) {
      this.props.lang = this.props.match.params.lng.toString();
    }
    else {
      this.props.lang = 'lt';
    }

    if (this.props.lang !== i18n.language) {

      i18n.changeLanguage(this.props.lang, (err) => {
        if (err) return console.log('something went wrong loading', err)
      });
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <Preloader />
        <Header />
        <SectionMain />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

It's seems that something has changed since that time.
How it could be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code was never correct, because it writes to `props`:

```
if ((typeof this.props.match.params.lng !== 'undefined') && ((this.props.match.params.lng == 'en') || (this.props.match.params.lng == 'lt'))) {
  this.props.lang = this.props.match.params.lng.toString();
}
else {
  this.props.lang = 'lt';
}
```

Your component is only supposed to *read* props from the props object, never *write* to it. The change is that React added enforcement of that by making the object non-extensible.

How you fix it depends on when you need that information how what you need to do with it (nothing in the code shown seems to *use* `this.props.lang`):

1. If it's just local to `render`, make it a local variable.
2. If it affects how you render the component, store it as state (and don't change state in `render`, do it once on creation or mount).
3. If it's instance-specific information that doesn't affect rendering, store it in a property on `this` (the component instance).

Re #2 and #3: Remember that `props` can **change** during the lifespan of the component instance. Props are effectively state managed by the parent rather than the component. So if you derive information from props, you need to re-derive it when props change.

Which possibly brings us to #4:

4. Have the parent provide a function to the component that lets the component update `lang`. When it does that, it'll get the new `lang` as updated props and will re-render.

Comment: Well, this was a language variable. Depending on URL code or language switch. But here it was a logic check: does the variable set, if not - set default language -> `lt`

Comment: @Kuzma - I'm afraid I don't understand the comment.

Comment: The `lang` stores language code of a current selected language. It could have two states: English language->'en' and Lithuanian->'lt'. But for a case when non of a two languages is not selected this code of piece was written. It checks if a variable is undefined - set the default language. So other components will have access to language's code. It wasn't correct but it served it's purpose in the past :)

Comment: @Kuzma - Sounds like you might want [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).